# LiveLoginResult.Status is Unknown?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying the code to find out whether the user has already signed in or not?

```
LiveAuthClient LCAuth = new LiveAuthClient();

LiveLoginResult LCLoginResult = await LCAuth.InitializeAsync();
```

Even if the user has already logged in, it returns Unknown.

What is the problem with this?

Comment: hello all,

Can anybody please suggest me a way to go with this?

Comment: Just a guess, but did you configure your app to use the live api? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826541.aspx

Comment: I will add that this is happening to me even when I pass in the client ID, which the docs say is all you need for a Windows Phone app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LiveAuthClient authCilent = new LiveAuthClient();

LiveLoginResult loginResult;

loginResult = authCilent.InitializeAsync().Result;

if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
   /* 
   Also use loginResult.Session as the Session which you will require to use live services by creating LiveConnectClient instance as follows.
   */

   // LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(loginResult.Session);

   // Write the logic you want by using liveClient instance
}
```

I had tried this snippet and it worked for me. Cheers

Comment: Sadly my problem is on Windows Phone. Have to use
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient("00000000xxxxxxxx");
authClient.InitializeCompleted += (o, args) =>
{ ...

Comment: if you're problem is on windows phone, perhaps ask a question with tagged accordingly - this one is tagged for win8

Comment: Thought they might have had the same root cause. I guess not.

Comment: @Kasun S Wanniarachchi I have tried your code and it hanged at: loginResult = authCilent.InitializeAsync().Result; Am I doing sth wrong? I'm using VS2013 running under win 8.1 and I'm trying to develop a windows store app. Thnx in advance.